# Trouble installing offline python library pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, offline, pyautogui

I am trying to install pyautogui (python library) on a closed system linux server. I'M NOT ALLOWED TO CONNECT TO THE INTERNET.  So far, I untarred the tarball, and went to the extracted folder.  I then run 'pip3 install pyautogui' and I get error:
"Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None__ after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannon connect to proxy.',NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection objects at 0x234343234>: Failed to establish a new connection [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))' : :/simple/setup-py

If I run 'python3 m pip install pyautogui': it tries to connect to the internet
"Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None__ after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannon connect to proxy.',NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection objects at 0x234343234>: Failed to establish a new connection [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))' : :/simple/pyautogui

I have tried the above and suspect it is trying to connect to the internet.  Every video/tutorial I watch says to connect to the internet on another system and download the package/library from the internet and compile everything that way, but I cannot do that due to our closed system process.

Comment: If you "went into the folder", you'll want `pip install .` to install the package from that directory.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer.  I did go into the pyautogui directory and then it errored out on a PyMsgBox dependency.  So I went into my PyMsgBox directory and ran 'pip install .' and then it errored out on simp/setuptools/,
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements setuptools>=40.9.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distructbution fround for setuptools>=40.8.0

When I run 'pip3 list' I do have setuptools 46.0.0 installed though.

Comment: You may want to try `pip install --no-build-isolation` then (see my [very recent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75628685/51685)).

Comment: It is asking for setuptools 40.8.0 just like the answer the post you responded with, however, I have setuptools 46.0.0 installed in the environment already.  Thoughts?  Also should I try 'pip3 install . --no-build-isolation' in the pyautogui directory and/or each dependencies directory?

Comment: As said (and in that answer), `--no-build-isolation`, or having a `setuptools` wheel available for `pip` to install it from. Otherwise `pip` will attempt to fetch and install a fresh `setuptools` from the internet.

Comment: You should be able to `pip install --no-build-isolation .` in each of the dependencies' folders, though actually it'd probably be better to just `pip install --find-links=. --no-build-isolation *.tar.gz *.whl` or whatever so pip can do its thing like it would online...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, and yes I am a noob.  But do I run pip install --find-links=. --no-build-isolation *.tar.gz *.whl     within the pyautogui directory or does that command essentially find every tar.gz and extract and install?  Also I have no .whl files when I ran that command.

Comment: No, I mean the directory where you have the tarballs. Don't uncompress them; let Pip deal with that.

Comment: I tried running the command pip install --find-links=. --no-build-isolation *.tar.gz *.whl, and it errored out saying it can't find any *.py files in the pymsgbox directory.  I went to the directory folder of pymsgbox, and tried the pip install pymsgbox, adn I got the ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements setuptools>=40.9.0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distructbution fround for setuptools>=40.8.0

Comment: Also, when I run 'pip list' I do see I have setuptools 46.0.0 installed, but maybe I need 40.8.0 to get this to work?  Do I need to rollback?

Comment: Can someone help1 please?